How can I put logo right next to maple institute of education?
I have problem that i want logo on exact left of heading maple institute of education. Can some one help plz. Currently i am getting logo alone on page 1 and then everything is fine from page 2. just logo problem.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[a4paper,
        bindingoffset=0.2in,
        left=0.2in,
        right=0.5in,
        top=1in,
        bottom=1in,
        footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}







\title {Maple Institute Of Education}   
\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2.2cm]{maple}
\maketitle



Mathematics    \hspace{5cm}     Max Marks : 30\\ 
Class X         \hspace{6.2cm}     Time : 1 hour
\\

\textbf{General Instructions}

All Questions are necessary.



\begin{enumerate}
\item In the given figure the tangent at a point C of a circle and diameter when extended intersect at P. If $\angle PCA = 110 ^\circ$, find $\angle CBA.$

\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4.5cm]{1}

\item AB is a diameter and AC is a chord of a circle with centre O such that $\angle BAC= 30^\circ.$ The tangent at C intersects AB produced ata point D. Prove that BC=BD.

\item If $d_1,d_2 (d_2 > d_1)$ be the diameters of two concentric circles and C be the length of a chord of a circle which is tangent to the other circle, prove that $d_2^2 = c^2 + d_1^2.$

\item A circle is inscribed in triangle ABC having sides 8 cm, 10 cm and 12 cm as shown in figure. Find AD, BE and CF.
\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4.5cm]{4}

\item If an isosceles triangle ABC in which AB = AC = 6 cm is inscribed in a circle of radius 9 cm, find the area of the triangle. 

\item In the given figure, tangents PQ and PR are drawn from an external point P to a circle with centre O such that $\angle RPQ = 30^\circ$. A chord RS is drawn parallel to the tangent PQ. Find $\angle RQS$.  
\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=4.5cm]{6}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


A few remarks: 1. No one has your image files, so you can use a built-in one  like cow with a specified width and height to make it compliable for others. 2. Breaking lines with \\\ is better done with just a blank line to avoid spacing issues. 3. While the example code is small, it is not very minimal. For instance, the enumerated items are unnecessary for the question. Best!

@Jasper please provide me with an answer where logo is next to heading. its really urgent. i am just a beginner in latex. thanks.

I mean, you could put the \includegraphics inside the \title command at the left. By the way, you should really not rush people on these sorts of things - people here are working for free.

@Jasper sorry i found a way.
\makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill
\begin{tabular}{c}
\large\bfseries Maple Institute Of Education \
\end{tabular}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{maple}}}%
}
can you help how can i put logo on left instead of right?

Update your question with that code, and make it more minimal. Admittedly, I am not an expert on title creation - I do graphics. Someone whose knowledge does encompass this skillset would be more inclined to help if you did those two things though. Best!

This question is similar to: Document class article, maketitle with logo. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note, that there are several other questions about [tag:graphics] and text in [tag:titles]. Search, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgraphics%5D+%5Btitles%5D+article
